# Help! External hard drive is not detected at all on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have been using the same 2TB external hard drive for over a year now and then today I went to plug it in and use it and it is not being detected at all! The light is on on the hard drive so it thinks it's running.

When I run `sudo fdisk -l`

I only get the following output:

```
 Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      718847      358400   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2          718848     7010303     3145728    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda3   *     7010304   468539391   230764544   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       468541438   500117503    15788033    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       468541440   500117503    15788032   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I'm starting to panic because all of my work is on that hard drive, does anyone have any advice?? Could this be because of my very old Ubuntu version??

Comment: Try run lsblk.  if that do not see your disk - the electronic in the box or on your disk are fried!!  But first tru to clean it for dust and spiderwebs etc. that might help!

Comment: See what the system thinks! First unplug your drive. Wait 10 seconds. Plug in your drive. Wait 10 seconds. Type `dmesg`. Did you last use the drive with Windows and fail to unmount it correctly?